# Global variable available across application

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable in main method with the name:

```
rows = []
```

The Main method in this file calls a method in a Class where some data is retrieved and written to Excel. In that Class, I am not able to access this variable. I want to do something like this in that Class:

```
Class Test:
  def GetData():
     data[] = <some data retrieved from DB>
     a.append(data)
```

This 'a' mentioned above is in another file which has the Main method. The Class Test is in another file.

I tried using 'global' keyword in the main file but still Class Test is unable to access 'a'.

Comment: You need to use `global rows` in both `main` and `GetData`. But using global variables is poor coding style, it's better to pass the variable as a parameter to all the functions that need it.

Comment: Is `a` supposed to be `rows`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes. These are rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the file like so:

file a:

```
rows = ['example', 'example1']
```

file b:

```
from [file a] import *
class Test:
  def GetData():
     #do stuff
     print(rows) # prints rows
Test().GetData()
```

output:

```
['example', 'example1']
```